# Mixpanel JQL filter two events with AND condition

Tags: mixpanel, jql

I have an query - Let's say If I want to see "Deal Viewed" AND then "Deal Claimed" how can I achieve this.I included these two events in event_selectors,I can see peoples who viewed the deal OR claimed deal. But I want AND instead of OR.

```
Below is my jql       
   function main()    {      
      return join(    
       Events({    
        from_date: '2017-08-24',   
       to_date:   '2017-08-24',    
         event_selectors:[{event:"Offer Viewed", selector: 'properties["Offer      
      Type"]=="Deal"' && 'properties["Offer 
     Title"]=="testDealtestDealtestDeal"'},    
                          {event:"Offer Claimed"}]      
      }),          
     People(),       
     { type:"inner"}       
   );      
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot do this directly. What you can do is find profile IDs that match your AND condition, i.e. profiles that have sent both events. You can do so using grouping on Events like this:

```
function main() {
  return Events({
    from_date: '2017-11-23',
    to_date:   '2017-11-24',
    event_selectors: [
      { event: "Offer Viewed", selector: 'properties["Offer      
  Type"] == "Deal"'},
      { event: "Offer Claimed"}
    ]
  })

  // Find unique event-name/ID pairs. There will be 1-2 rows for each ID.
  .groupBy(["name", "properties.$id"], mixpanel.reducer.any())
  .map(e => { return {"event" : e.key[0], "id" : e.key[1]} })

  // Find IDs for profiles that sent both events
  // (i.e. that are returning 2 items after grouping on ID)
  .groupBy(["id"], mixpanel.reducer.count())
  .filter(e => { return e.value === 2})
  .map(e => { return {"id" : e.key[0]} })
}
```

But when you try to join it with People(), you'll are bound to get stuck with this restriction of JQL:

```
Error validating script: Uncaught exception Error: join(Events(), People()) is the only form of join JQL supports.
  return join(
```

One way around this is to set some profile property as well whenever you send events. What we use a lot is a pattern where, let's say when you send Offer Viewed, you also do a profile update and set profile property `Offer Viewed At=$timestamp`. That way you could skip working with Events here, and just do the filtering on profile properties.

Your other option is to use the query above, and try to get the rest of what you need done on the level of Events.